# Array to print images in HTML

Tags: php, arrays

I want in PHP to generate the following code:

```
<img src"images/logo1.png" alt="Compagny 1">
<img src"images/logo2.png" alt="Compagny 2">
<img src"images/logo3.png" alt="Compagny 3">
```

How with an array I can generate this list ?

Comment: Yes, with an array you can generate that list.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Do you know about foreach loops? http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Set up the array.

```
<?php 
$images = array(
    0 => array(
        'src' => 'IMAGESRC',
        'alt' => 'IMAGEALT'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'src' => 'IMAGESRC',
        'alt' => 'IMAGEALT'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'src' => 'IMAGESRC',
        'alt' => 'IMAGEALT'
    ),
);
?>
```

Step #2: Create a loop to itterate over above array and print out requested. [Foreach Loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach($images as $img) {
    echo "<img src='" . $img['src'] ."' alt='" . $img['alt'] . "'/> \n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array('Company1'=>'logo1.png','Company2'=>'logo2.png','Company3'=>'logo3.png');

foreach($array as $key=>$var){
     echo '<img src"images/'.$var.'" alt="'.$key.'">';
}
```

Here you go. :)